# Xml Schema / JaxB -- How to enable empty enumerations, string, integer values in schema without validation errors?

Tags: jaxb, xsd

I tried a couple of things:

1)

```
<xs:simpleType name="matchAnalysisType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
        <xs:enumeration value=""/>
    </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
```

JaxB DOESN'T generate enums and instead marks matchAnalysisType as string for the corresponding element type.

2) Use 'nillable':

```
 <xs:element name="matchAnalysisType" type="matchAnalysisType"  
     nillable="true">                
 </xs:element>
```

JaxB throws error that '' is not valid.

The issue holds true for other element types like the following:

```
 <xs:element name="accountNumber" minOccurs="0">                
     <xs:simpleType>
         <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
             <xs:totalDigits value="9"/>
         </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

I'd like to have a sample xml that allows this the following without any validation errors.

```
 <accountNumber></accountNumber>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

JAXB does not have a default enum value name for enum values corresponding to "".   Your JAXB implementation can generate a Java enum corresponding to this XML schema type if you use an external bindings file to provide a name.

**binding.xml**

```
<jxb:bindings
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="your-schema.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='matchAnalysisType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="BLANK"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

The binding file is specified in the XJC call using the `-b` parameter:

```
xjc -b binding.xml your-schema.xsd
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-enums.html

Comment: pleas seemmy response above. FYI, not sure how you can add a large  'comment' to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution :

tyesafeEnumMemberName has by default value generateError and you can specify value generateName.

This attribute was not present in our xjc file.  Now this fixes the autogneration.

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="your.xsd" node="/xsd:schema"> 
                <jxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="9000"         typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName" >
                            <xjc:simple/>
            </jxb:globalBindings>
```